# como faço para diferenciar cpf estrangeiros e nacionais em javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou fazendo um sistema que precisa validar o campo cpf brasileiros porém se o cpf for estrangeiro não precisa validar a parte de validação do cpf está OK, porém como eu colocaria na função para ele desconsiderar cpf estrangeiros.

segue o código:

```
//valida o CPF
function verificarCPF(c){
    var i;
    s = c;
    var c = s.substr(0,9);
    var dv = s.substr(9,2);
    var d1 = 0;
    var v = false;

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        d1 += c.charAt(i)*(10-i);
    }
    if (d1 == 0){
        alert("CPF Inválido")
        v = true;
        return false;
    }
    d1 = 11 - (d1 % 11);
    if (d1 > 9) d1 = 0;
    if (dv.charAt(0) != d1){
        alert("CPF Inválido")
        v = true;
        return false;
    }

    d1 *= 2;
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        d1 += c.charAt(i)*(11-i);
    }
    d1 = 11 - (d1 % 11);
    if (d1 > 9) d1 = 0;
    if (dv.charAt(1) != d1){
        alert("CPF Inválido")
        v = true;
        return false;
    }
    if (!v) {
        //alert(c + "nCPF Válido")
    }
}
```

Comment: O que é um CPF estrangeiro?

Comment: CPF é um documento brasileiro. Logo, acredito que todo CPF deveria ser validado caso inserido. Claro, se o CPF estrangeiro que você estiver se referindo for aquele CPF que é feito para pessoas estrangeiras que vêm para o Brasil.

Comment: CPF de estrangeiro é diferente?

Comment: A pergunta ficou meio vaga por exemplo você quer saber um estrangeiro que possua CPF (documento Brasileiro),
Ou um documento estrangeiro como o número do serviço social nos EUA que seria o equivalente ao nosso CPF
Se for o CPF não há como o último dígito antes do dígito verificador é referente a região fiscal do Brasil onde foi emitido o CPF

Comment: CPF de estrangeiro é igual ao CPF de brasileiro. Tem o mesmo padrão de números.

Answer (score 4):

O CPF de brasileiros e estrangeiros tem o mesmo número de dígitos, logo, a validação sempre será a mesma e não há como diferencia-los baseados apenas na numeração.

Acredito que não exista uma API para você consultar essa informação, contudo, o que você pode fazer é criar um select na sua página indicando a nacionalidade do CPF, e caso seja estrangeiro não ocorra a validação.

Exemplo:

```html
<label>Nacionalidade CPF</label>
<select id="nacionalidadeCPF">
  <option value="1">Nacional</option>
  <option value="2">Estrangeiro</option>
</select>
```

E na sua function:

```
function verificarCPF(c){
     var nacionalidade = document.getElementById('nacionalidadeCPF').value;
     if (nacionalidade == 2) return true;

     ...
     ...
}
```